# grid to list view and vice versa in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

I want to add option in the actionbar to change my record display from grid to list and vice versa. you can see an example here:

**ListView**

[ListView http://cdn.androidblip.com/screens/1____170969.png](http://cdn.androidblip.com/screens/1____170969.png)

**GridView**

[GridView http://cdn.androidblip.com/screens/2____170969.png](http://cdn.androidblip.com/screens/2____170969.png)

So please, is there any open source or example code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do when option is selected call the gridview activity and when list option is selected call the listview activity in one clicklistener

Comment: thanks for your solution, but in this case every view (grid or list) need it's own action for it's records which they are have same action.

Answer (score 1):

or else based on the selection u can do like this

`if(selectedItem == list)
setContentView(R.id.list)
 else
 setContenView(R.id.grid)`
 then you can have the same actions performed no need to rewrite the same code